# mysql query needed for complex move of 1 field into a field in a different database

Tags: mysql, database

I have a db called `LTC_OLD` with a table called `phpbb_users` and a field called `user_gender`.

I also have a second db called `LTC_NEW` with a table called `pfields_content` and a field called `field_5`.

Each table contains many rows, (a row for each user_id)
The id rows are named `user_id` in `phpbb_users` and `member_id` in `pfields_content`.

I need to take the values from `user_gender` and place into `field_5`.
Each row matching or joining on `user_id` to `member_id`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: moving data across databases is usually easiest to do by exporting from one db to a file and importing from that file into the other db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming both databases are on the same server, you can do an `update join` between the two. Yu just need to qualify the table names with which database they are in:

```
update LTC_NEW.pfields_content c
  join LTC_OLD.phpbb_users u on c.member_id = u.user_id
SET c.field_5 = u.user_gender
```